# how to use increment() and decrement() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table `total_count`

```
+----+--------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | studid | month | year | acls_id | total_p | total_a |
+----+--------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1  |   30   |  08   | 2015 |   12    |    5    |    2    |
| 2  |   35   |  08   | 2015 |   12    |    5    |    2    |
| 3  |   52   |  08   | 2015 |   12    |    5    |    2    |
| 4  |   53   |  08   | 2015 |   12    |    5    |    2    |
| 5  |   54   |  08   | 2015 |   12    |    5    |    2    |
| 6  |   55   |  08   | 2015 |   12    |    5    |    2    |
| 7  |   30   |  09   | 2015 |   12    |    3    |    0    |
| 8  |   35   |  09   | 2015 |   12    |    3    |    0    |
| 9  |   52   |  09   | 2015 |   12    |    2    |    1    |
| 10 |   53   |  09   | 2015 |   12    |    3    |    0    |
| 11 |   54   |  09   | 2015 |   12    |    3    |    0    |
| 12 |   55   |  09   | 2015 |   12    |    3    |    0    |
+----+--------+-------+------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want to increment and decrement for each student `total_p` and `total_a`.

when i am edit my student attendance list.

> **eg:** studid 30 total_p = 5 and total_a= 2 ,so iam edit my attendance present become absent .

so want decrement total_p by 1 and increment total_a by 1.

So I'd like to get the total of each month for each `studid` and a increment and decrement of  `total_p` and `total_a` for the total months.

My **controller** code is

```
foreach ($student as $student) {
            if ($present == 0) {
                $query = DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)
                    ->where('studid', $student->id)
                    ->where('smonth', '=', $date_exploded[1])
                    ->where('syear', '=', $date_exploded[2])
                    ->update([
                        'stotal_p' => DB::raw('stotal_p - 1'),
                        'stotal_a' => DB::raw('stotal_a + 1'),
                    ]);
            } elseif ($present == 1) {
                $query = DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)
                    ->where('studid', $student->id)
                    ->where('smonth', '=', $date_exploded[1])
                    ->where('syear', '=', $date_exploded[2])
                    ->update([
                        'stotal_p' => DB::raw('stotal_p + 1'),
                        'stotal_a' => DB::raw('stotal_a - 1'),
                    ]);
            }
        }
```

but it doesn't work..

How to use `increment()` and `decrement()` in query builder format?

> **for eg:**  if i only edit studid = 30 attendance increment total_p value 1 and (present == 1) studid = 30 total_p = 6 and total_a = 1 and other
>   studid values are old value.

Comment: Are you sure your SQL logic is correct?

Comment: sorry i dont know...but i want like this ... if (present==1) then increment (stotal_p,1) and decrement (stotal_a,1) and if (present==0) then increment (stotal_a,1) and decrement (stotal_p,1) with these where conditions are true.

Comment: Convert your builder code into a MySQL query and run it against the attendance table.

Comment: if you dont mind ..my logic is wrong...can you tell me what is correct code??

Comment: sir i dont want convert my builder code into mysql....how to use increment ()and decrement () in query builder??

Comment: I think you are missing my point.  I want you to run the query with the same logic to see whether the `WHERE` clause actually returns any records.

Comment: yes sir,,, iam run my   above code. i got wrong answer if excute (present==1) increment the 1st student total_p value 1's (not correcsponding student value)and got one error Call to a member function decrement() on a non-object

Answer (score 22):

**increment()** and **decrement()** do not return a **Query Builder** object, so you cannot chain your calls like you do in your code:

```
->increment('stotal_p', 1)->decrement('stotal_a', 1);
```

You'll need to call each method separately. Moreover, **1** is the default value for the **increment/decrement**, so no need to pass it.

This should do the trick:

```
$query = DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)
  ->where('studid',$student->id)                                     
  ->where('smonth','=',$date_exploded[1])
  ->where('syear','=',$date_exploded[2]);

$query->increment('stotal_a');
$query->decrement('stotal_p');
```

Comment: sir this code work fine ..but one problem  when i am edit one student (eg:studid =35) ,i want to execute this code only that studid(35) raw ,not all other students... like **update** function with increment and decrement. using this code change all studid values.

Comment: There is a where() constraint on studid so it is not possible for the query to update other studids. Paste some more of your code and we'll find the reason

Comment: Do "dd($student->id, $query->toSql());" and paste the result

Comment: sir i got an error message.. Call to a member function toSql() on a non-object

Comment: Do this on the query in the answer, not in query in your code

Comment: sorry,,, how its possible... i  want  to save increment and decrement value into database table. how can  this on the query in the answer.??sorry i dont.know...

Comment: dd(DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)
  ->where('studid',$student->id)                                     
  ->where('smonth','=',$date_exploded[1])
  ->where('syear','=',$date_exploded[2]))

Answer (score 9):

From Laravel 5.7+ you can increment or decrement the given column by using `increment()` or `decrement()` methods without writing the manual update statement.

#### Laravel Doc & Example

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#increment-and-decrement

```
DB::table('users')->increment('votes');
DB::table('users')->increment('votes', 5);

DB::table('users')->decrement('votes');
DB::table('users')->decrement('votes', 5);
```

#### Get the Student Attendance

```
$studentAtd = DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)
  ->where('studid',$student->id)                                     
  ->where('smonth','=',$date_exploded[1])
  ->where('syear','=',$date_exploded[2]);
```

#### Increment or Decrement Attendance column

```
$studentAtd->increment('stotal_a');
$studentAtd-> decrement('stotal_p');
```

Comment: Those helpers are since 5.3 https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#increment-and-decrement